# AWS postgres db instance is not listening to 5432 port

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.3

I have created a postgres db instance on AWS but I am unable to connect to it.
Its host is not even listening to port (5432). 
AWS configuration are :

VPC : default

DB Subnet Group : default

Publicly Accessible : **YES**

CIDR/IP - Inbound : 0.0.0.0/0

CIDR/IP - Outbound : 0.0.0.0/0

and its on EC2-VPC platform

Don't know what should be done. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've used an AWS instance before, and manually setup postgres on my instance. I'm not sure if this is your situation, but if it is, these are issues I've run into before:

- For Postgres, make sure you have remote access setup in postgresql.conf. Also, make sure you have the right client authentication settings in pg_hba.conf.   ie. using trust instead of ident. There are a lot of sites, search for "postgres remote Linux", or something to that effect.
- The other thing that usually gets me is iptables. Once again, I'd suggest doing a google search on something like, "setting up iptables for a specific port"

I'd rather make this a comment, but I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: There are `listen_addresses` and `port` configurations in `postgresql.conf` file. They are needed for remote access to postgres.

Comment: Indeed. Kishore might need to update that too. I'll modify the answer to recognize that. I just remember banging my head against a client authentication issue recently, and for me, it was that I was using ident, instead of trust, in the pg_hba.